# Postgres - How to configure the number of transaction log file?

Tags: postgresql, logging

In Postgres, how to configure the number of transaction xlog file ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow! Stackoverflow is not really meant for server administration questions, its rather for programming questions. I'm voting to migrate this question to server fault.

Comment: This [link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-admin.html) might help you.

Comment: @GeekyNinja: please do not link to the manual of completely outdated Postgres versions. A **lot** has changed in 10 years